# How do I use the Wood Elf's 'Command Animal' effectively?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have chosen to be a Wood Elf and was looking forward to the command animal skill they have. However I fail to see how it is a valuable asset as all it does is create a static, uncontrollable meat shield.

Is there something I am missing?

What is a good situation to be using this skill in?

Comment: I also cannot for the life of me even actually "cast" the spell... I've bound it to a favorite, and "equipped" it as far as I can see, but every animal I target just.... like, never casts anything...

Comment: @ixobelle select it under the "powers" menu in your magic page, then to use it, use the same button as shout. It even works on mammoths, which is super useful :)

Comment: What button is shout? Ane my tv cuts of some of the text which is shown after i try to command animal

Comment: It is RB on the Xbox 360, R2 on the PS3, or Z on the PC. If you have more powerful versions on the shout then hold the button down.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, all of the short-duration, uncontrollable summons/commands are incredibly useful precisely *because* they are on-demand meat shields: having the enemy attack something else while you finish them off is pretty useful, particularly if you and your followers aren't cutting it. Strength in numbers and all that.

But *Command Animal* is particularly effective for two reasons:

- It affects nearly every animal in the game, and boy there are a lot of animals. You'll be hard pressed not to find a place outdoors where you can't use it.
- When fighting a group of animals, it takes one of them out of the picture in addition to helping you attack the rest. So if it's 3 vs. 1 against you, commanding an animal makes it a fair fight.
- It's a decent substitute for the *Animal Allegiance* shout, so if you were planning on using it, it frees up your shout slot for something else.

Playing around with summons might not be your play-style: even conjuration isn't for everyone. But if you're looking for a way to manipulate fights to your advantage instead of sneaking around or straight up attacking, *Command Animal* is a great racial ability.

Comment: How do you use the command? I can't figure that out...

Comment: @hoss3000 select it under the "powers" menu in your magic page, then to use it, use the same button as shout.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it much on my Wood Elf but one time it helped me beat a Master Vampire.

It still makes no sense to me. The Master Vampire hit really hard, one power attack and I was dead. There were a few wolves that were freed from cages. I could kill the wolves easily, and the wolves wouldn't hurt me much.

After retrying this fight twenty times or so (each time killing the wolves before taking on the Vampires), I tried Command Animal on one of the wolves.

The wolf chewed the Master Vampire's ass enough to make it kneel to the floor that I only had to finish it. Go figure!